# ./batchTest.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `;' ./batchTest.sh: line 4: ` ./test 1>&;'

Tags: shell, for-loop

I have wrote a simple shell, but it doesn't work:

```
#! /bin/sh -x
for i in `seq 0 0`
do
    ./test&;
done
```

When I run this code, I get a failure:

```
./batchTest.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
./batchTest.sh: line 4: `       ./test&;'
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code,

```
#!/bin/sh -x
for i in `seq 0 0`
do
    ./test &
done
```

Comment: It's worked, why?Just add a semicolon，It doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. A ';' and '&' in a shell script is a command terminator. ';' means “run the preceding command in the foreground” and & means “run the preceding command in the background”.